# omniauth redirect_callbacks not working when using devise_token_auth gem alongside regular devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, ionic-framework, omniauth

I am trying to get ng-token-auth, devise_token_auth and omniauth-facebook to work together in a rails/angular (actually ionic) app working alongside of the regular devise.

What happens is that when the user clicks on the login through facebook button, the browser is redirected to facebook and once the app is authorized, I see a facebook callback request in my server logs:

```
https://<app>.herokuapp.com/omniauth/facebook/callback?code=<some_code>&state=<state>
```

This request gets a 302 response from my server to make the following request:

```
https://<app>.herokuapp.com/users/facebook/callback
```

This request ends up in a 404 because the route for /users/facebook/callback does not exist in my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
namespace :api do
  scope :v1 do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
  end
end
```

which generates the following (relevant) routes:

```
api_v1_auth_validate_token_path GET /api/v1/auth/validate_token(.:format)       devise_token_auth/token_validations#validate_token
api_v1_auth_failure_path        GET /api/v1/auth/failure(.:format)              devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                                GET /api/v1/auth/:provider/callback(.:format)   devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_success
                                GET /omniauth/:provider/callback(.:format)      devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#redirect_callbacks
omniauth_failure_path           GET /omniauth/failure(.:format)                 devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
```

I don't understand where the request to /users/facebook/callback is coming from. From what I understand it should really redirect to /api/v1/auth/:provider/callback.

Anyone have an idea what I am missing? It would be great to get some help/pointers in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working and it seems to be an bug(?) with devise_token_auth (0.1.34).  As a workaround and to prevent the callback redirection to /users/facebook/callback, I replaced this commented line of the redirect_callbacks method in omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb by the one below it:

```
#redirect_route = "/#{Devise.mappings[devise_mapping].as_json["path"]}/#{params[:provider]}/callback"
redirect_route = "/api/v1/auth/#{params[:provider]}/callback"
```

It's ugly but it works for now. I opened [this issue](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/362) with the project at GitHub.